# Resolution of singularities of projective varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, birational-geometry, blow-ups, resolution-of-singularities

Let $X\subset\mathbb{P}^n$ be an irreducible variety, and let $Sing(X)$ be its singular locus. Let $Y$ be the blow-up of $\mathbb{P}^n$ along $Sing(X)$. Assume that we know that the strict transform of $X$ in $Y$ is smooth.

Now, let $W\subset\mathbb{P}^n$ be a smooth variety such that $Sing(X)\subset W\subset X$, and let $Z$ be the blow-up of $\mathbb{P}^n$ along $W$. Is it true that the strict transform of $X$ in $Z$ is smooth?

Comment: With your current wording, consider the case when the intersection of $X$ and $W$ is already a Cartier divisor in $X$.  Do you want to assume that the intersection of $W$ with $X$ *equals* $\text{Sing}(X)$?

Comment: No, in my case $Sing(X)$ has codimension two in $X$ while $W$ has codimension one. Since $Sing(X)\subset W$ the divisor $W$ in $X$ is not necessarily Cartier. Take for instance a quadric cone in $\mathbb{P}^3$ and a line in it.

Comment: The point of my first comment is that the result cannot possibly hold in the special case that $X\cap W$ is a Cartier divisor in $X$.  There may be some special cases where the result does hold if $X\cap W$ is merely a Weil divisor.  However, you will need to add some additional hypotheses.